# WiFly does not name a type, wiflyhq

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to run an example on an rv-nx the code is simply the httpclient, and it has a sentece

```
Wifly wifly;
```

and I get the error 'WiFly' does not name a type, I know what it means, but i think It  shouldn't happen. what's going on?

Comment: Did you remember to include the relevant header?

Comment: Yes i Did, that's why i'm stuck , I know it's there and the library it's properly in it's place